# Implementation of text search with dropdown answers in Angular and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

What is the correct implementation of a text search (triggering on key up) to display a list of Countries that the user can then select as a choice. I've come up with some code below but couldn't see any other examples online.

At present selecting the  link in the repeated list will not inject into the model, but I can't see a way of making bootstrap work with a traditional select in this way?

Please see example code below:

```
        <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="country" ng-keyup="searchCountry()"
               placeholder="Search country">

        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                    data-toggle="dropdown">Country <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                <li placeholder="Country" ng-model="country" ng-repeat="country in countries"><a
                        href="">{{country}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to implement this is using the AngularStraps addon and using typeaheads:

http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##typeaheads